# shiny dowloadHandler (ERROR: replacement has length zero)

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am working on some simply shiny app which allows user to download a R generated csv file, but encounter some difficulties when using shiny download button

Here is my code example
At UI side,

```
body <- dashboardBody(

tabItem("output1",
        fluidRow(
          infoBox(title = "Download Output File", color = "lime", fill = TRUE, icon = icon("cloud-download"), width = 6, uiOutput(outputId = "downloadAction")
          )      
        )
)
```

)
)

At Server side,
my calculation returns a list with status either false or true, and also the data frame need to be put into the download file

```
server <- function(input, output) {
 calculation <- reactive({...})
 output$downloadAction <- renderUI({
    cal <- calculation()
    if (!cal$status) return()
    downloadButton(outputId = "downloadFiles", label = "Download Available")
  })

  output$downloadFiles <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      # Create download data file
        filename <- paste0("data-", Sys.Date(), "-", floor(runif(1, 1, 10000)), ".csv")
        while (file.exists(filename)) {
          filename <- paste0("data-", Sys.Date(), "-", floor(runif(1, 1, 10000)), ".csv")
        }
      }, 
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(calculation()$data, file)
    } 
  )
}
```

But this results in an error message "ERROR: replacement has length zero"
I know it is because of some null value being sent to R which expect non null value, but have no clue what the root cause and how to fix it. 
Thanks for your suggestions

#

I think I figured out the problem
inside the file name function, you cannot assign the string to a variable

```
filename = function() {
          # Create download data file
            filename <- paste0("data-", Sys.Date(), "-", floor(runif(1, 1, 10000)), ".csv")
            while (file.exists(filename)) {
              filename <- paste0("data-", Sys.Date(), "-", floor(runif(1, 1, 10000)), ".csv")
            }
          }, 
        content = function(file) {
          write.csv(calculation()$data, file)
        } 
      )
```

I changed to

```
filename = function() {
          # Create download data file
            paste0("data-", Sys.Date(), "-", floor(runif(1, 1, 10000)), ".csv")
          }, 
        content = function(file) {
          write.csv(calculation()$data, file)
        }
```

It works now. I guess Shiny should be able to handle file name conflict since it always creates temporary file name, so there is no need to detect file name conflict in the code?